# Does the Codecademy codebit window distort the real appearance of a website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

https://www.codecademy.com/Jack-Aaron/codebits/vL8j7y/

This is a site I'm working on.  All the code is there.  It looks pretty nice in the editor's browsing window.  However, when I copy-paste all the code into an index.html and style.css file respectively on my computer and then open that in a browser, the styling looks completely different.  The image is misplaced, the sections are different sizes and it just looks wrong.  Why is that?

I think this may have something to do with the answer:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css">
```

That's how I load Bootstrap into the page because that's what I was "taught" by Codecademy.  Does this work outside of the Codecademy browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow! Now, that is how it will work. The reason it looks odd is because your whole website is designed using pixels. That will make it look funky on all screens, EXCEPT the one it was designed on.

To make it look correct, you should (NEED) to use percentages. Now, why it looks weird on there, and other places? They all are different sized places, like for instance, on Codecademy it is a small preview window.

Yes, it will look funky, use percentages, not pixels.

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  I'll go back and toy with everything changing the pixels to percentages until I get it how I like it.

Comment: @JonathanAaronAlpart, Glad to help! :) I designed my first website on Codecademy too, and I used pixels. I guess we all make that mistake

Comment: No way!  So it is common practice to always use percentages?  Are you now a web designer?

Comment: @JonathanAaronAlpart, Yes I am, and Percentages are the easiest to use :) There are other forms, but don't use pixels for layouts.